# Add seq number by group SAS

Tags: sas

I need to assign seq number by group. I have tried using seq number but got it by one group (1,2,3, etc). However, I need it by two groups. As in the example below:

[image]

Have:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3
101 aaa 202 
101 aaa 202 
101 bbb 203 
101 ccc 206 
101 ddd 207 
102 aaa 222 
102 aaa 222 
102 bbb 223
```

Want:

```
Obs var1 var2 var3 seq
1   101 aaa 202 1
2   101 aaa 202 1
3   101 bbb 203 2
4   101 ccc 206 3
5   101 ddd 207 4
6   102 aaa 222 1
7   102 aaa 222 1
8   102 bbb 223 2
```

Comment: Please post your sample data as text, not as an image.

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to enter it as text as in the pic. Here is the data:
101 aaa 202 
101 aaa 202
101 bbb 203
101 ccc  206
101 ddd 207
102 aaa 222
102 aaa 222
102 bbb 223

Comment: @Sammy Look at any number of other SAS questions here.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the data, not in comments. You lose all formatting in comments. I added it in, it took me less than 10 minutes. Consider if you're not willing to spend that time to format your data, why should we to answer your question? ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you sort your data it is quite simple:

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
    by sex age;
run;

data class;
    set class;
    by sex age;

    if first.sex then
        seqn = 0;   

    if first.age then
        seqn + 1;
run;
```

Comment: Thank Robert, I tried as in your example. However, it is continuous. I need to start from 1 again in next group. i,e. Var1 - 102 should start with 1 and not continuous from previous seq number.

In your example, Sex=M should start with 1 again.

Comment: @Sammy That is what the `by` group is for.

Comment: Now it works after adding the second by group. Thanks a lot.